# Instagram API Usage

Tags: facebook, instagram

I'm currently working on a project where I'm "tracking" down public instagram users' statics.

But I'm encountering an issue, I'm able to get my own profile but not other's profile, even if their profile is public.

On my Facebook developer's app I don't have the authorizations to use their API (basic / graph profile), but to fill the form I need to show to Facebook how I'm using it on my website, but everything is currently backend, and I can't work on a frontend page if I can't test my api on other  profile.

What am I supposed to do ?

PS: I don't mind the language, if it's functional I will adapt it to my system's language.

Best regards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will get API approval for such purpose (but who knows..) so your best bet might be unofficial API wrappers from github.

Comment: Okay, I will check it out, thanks !
Just one more thing, does instalyze.me give you the number of likes of a media / comments of a media ?

Comment: it depends on the query you are talking about, but in general, yes.

Comment: I made some tests with instalyze.me and it's just what I want, thanks a lot !